# Extensive object composition

Tags: python, django, composition

I have a Django model that has a lot of methods (and will continue to have more in the future) because it is central to the app. It is a custom User model that interfaces with a legacy database. There are methods that check the user's access permissions to different areas, different kinds of costs, etc.

Since there are groups of methods that relate to each other, it makes sense to break them out into separate classes and use object composition. My question, though, is how to make that appear to the end developer. Should they use object chains, such as `user.access.has_normal_access()`, or should there be methods on the User object that simply pass through to the underlying object?

Object chaining seems to be discouraged in Python, but the alternative of creating pass-through methods seems to be at odds with the purpose, which is to reduce the number of methods in the primary class.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split out methods on the same underlying db model into different sets of related methods, perhaps you should use [proxy models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Same underlying db will be used, but will be different distinct classes.

I am not sure that this is the best solution when you are talking about `User` class though. You haven't given enough details for me to say for sure, but surely you could use the [builtin permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#handling-object-permissions) to achieve what you intend to?

Comment: Proxy models will be valuable, but there are a lot of methods that all users need to have, such as checking permissions to know whether certain navigation elements should appear on the page.

Also, we're not using the Django `User` model, but one written to interface with a legacy database table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume non-django, pure python solution using decorators is ok for you.

Please, consider following code

```
def check1(): print "check1"
def check2(): print "check2"

def dev_api(f):
    def fd(*args, **kw):
        check1()
        check2()
        f(*args, **kw)
        # optionally, perform some post check
        print "post check"
    return fd

@dev_api
def business(a, b, *args, **kw):
    print 'business', a, b, args, kw

business(1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', x='x', y='y')
```

- check1, check2 your persmission, different cost functions, etc.
- dev_api is your "check" functions grouping function
- business is business logic function, which execution needs to be constrained by your "check" functions

now, you can expose business logic functions decorated as above or expose decorators themselves for end developer consumption.

there is bit more to learn with decorators (i.e. decorators with parameters). please, feel free to request more examples, if needed.

the output of above code

```
check1
check2
business 1 2 ('a', 'b', 'c') {'y': 'y', 'x': 'x'}
post check
```

Comment: Decorators would work for the view functions, but the same checks are also needed in the templates and in other areas. You may be onto something with decorators though: is there a class decorator solution to explore?

Comment: unfortunately, i am not familiar with Django enough to say if decorators is the solution for every aspect of using Django, but imho function/method and class decorators might be worth exploring.